# How to replace Integer objects with primitives

Tags: java

I am making  a datastucture where I can:

- add pair with start and end positions
- can get list of pairs test
- interval for having gaps

E.g. add (0,2),(0,1),(3,4),(6,8)
it will return (0,4),(6,8)
check(2,4) - true
check(3,8) - false, as there is a gap between 4 and 6.

How can I modify the code below, such as set `list` and list `data` will contain primitive `int` instead of object `Integer`?

**EDIT:** I am aware that java generics cannot be an primitives, so List is impossible. My motivation comes from implementation of other data stuctures.
e.g HashMap< Integer, Object> is basicly same thing as android SparseArray with diffenrece that SparseArray ussed ints instead of Integers for keys.

```
public class GapAwareList {
  Set<Integer> list = new HashSet<>();

  public void put(int start, int end) {
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      list.add(i);
    }
  }

  public void remove(int start, int end) {
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      list.remove(i);
    }
  }

  public List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> getPairs() {
    List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.addAll(list);
    Collections.sort(data);
    List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
    int last = data.get(data.size() - 1);
    int s = -1;
    int e;
    for (int i = 0; i <= last; i++) {
      if (list.contains(i)) {
        if (s == -1) {
          s = i;
        }
        e = i;
        if (!list.contains(i + 1)) {
          Pair<Integer, Integer> p = new Pair<>(s, e);
          pairs.add(p);
          s = -1;
        }
      }
    }
    return pairs;
  }

  public boolean haveGap(int start, int end) {
    boolean b = false;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
      if (!list.contains(i)) {
        b = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    return b;
  }
}
public class Pair {
  public final int first;
  public final int second;

  public Pair(int first, int second) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
  }

}
public class ExampleUnitTest {

  @Test public void gapSize() throws Exception {
    GapAwareList gaps = fillGaps();

    gaps.put(0, 2);
    gaps.put(0, 1);
    gaps.put(3, 4);
    gaps.put(6, 8);
    List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairs = gaps.getPairs();

    assertEquals(3, pairs.size());
  }

  @Test public void gapFirst() throws Exception {
    GapAwareList gaps = fillGaps();

    gaps.put(0, 2);
    gaps.put(0, 1);
    gaps.put(3, 4);
    gaps.put(6, 8);
    List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairs = gaps.getPairs();

    assertTrue(pairs.get(0).first == 0);
    assertTrue(pairs.get(0).second == 4);
  }

  @Test public void gapSecond() throws Exception {
    GapAwareList gaps = fillGaps();
    List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairs = gaps.getPairs();

    assertTrue(pairs.get(1).first == 6);
    assertTrue(pairs.get(1).second == 8);
  }

  private GapAwareList fillGaps() {
    GapAwareList gaps = new GapAwareList();
    //add (0,2),(0,1),(3,4),(6,8)
    gaps.put(0, 2);
    gaps.put(3, 4);
    gaps.put(0, 1);
    gaps.put(6, 8);
    gaps.put(13,11);
    gaps.put(13, 13);
    gaps.put(13, 14);

    return gaps;
  }
  @Test public void checkGaps(){
    GapAwareList gaps = fillGaps();
    assertFalse(gaps.haveGap(0,4));
    assertFalse(gaps.haveGap(6, 8));
    assertFalse(gaps.haveGap(6, 7));
    assertTrue(gaps.haveGap(4, 6));
  }
}
```

Comment: JAVA Generics doesn't support primitives. If you want it that way, you can create an explicit array.

Comment: Are you asking for a list implementation which disallows gaps, or about generics?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen about generics. e.g HashMap< Integer, Object> is basicly same thing as android SparseArray<Object> with diffenrece that SparseArray ussed ints instead of Integers for keys

Comment: @PriyanshGoel yes, I am aware about that, please, look at edit to my topic

Comment: Did you consider creating a class e.g. `Range` that holds the integers and have a `List<Range>`?

Comment: You can implement your own hashtable that uses `int` for keys. That's not too difficult. With the collection types you get from Java's standard libs, you won't have luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Java documentation "Restrictions on Generics"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#instantiate) :

> **Cannot Instantiate Generic Types with Primitive Types**
>
> Consider the following parameterized type:
>
> ```
> class Pair<K, V> {
>
>     private K key;
>     private V value;
>
>     public Pair(K key, V value) {
>         this.key = key;
>         this.value = value;
>     }
>
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> When creating a `Pair` object, you cannot substitute a primitive type
>   for the type parameter `K` or `V`:
>
> ```
> Pair<int, char> p = new Pair<>(8, 'a');  // compile-time error
> ```
>
> You can substitute only non-primitive types for the type parameters
>   `K` and `V`:
>
> ```
> Pair<Integer, Character> p = new Pair<>(8, 'a');
> ```
>
> Note that the Java compiler autoboxes `8` to `Integer.valueOf(8)` and `'a'`
>   to `Character('a')`:
>
> ```
> Pair<Integer, Character> p = new Pair<>(Integer.valueOf(8), new Character('a'));
> ```
>
> For more information on autoboxing, see [Autoboxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) in the
>   [Numbers and Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/index.html) lesson.

Comment: Well, if you know this, then don't use generics.